# debugg not going inside the loop

Tags: c, debugging, char

I am practicing on chars and i wrote a while loop that ends whenver i see a ";"

however when i am trying to debug it doesnt go inside the loop only at the last loop and I dont understand why

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    void main()
{
    char str[] = "abccc;";
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != ';') 
    {
        i++;
        printf("%d \n",i);
    }

}
```

thats the code, it works and realy simple but if I debugg to see it only goes inside the loop in the last time
I am not sure why and how to fix

Comment: Not reproducible here. -> https://godbolt.org/z/-xXVQY -  It gives the expected output. Only thing is that `void main ()` should be `int main ()`. Seems to be a specific problem with your debugger. Which debugger you use?

Comment: Note: For the provided code you don´t need to include `stdlib.h` and `string.h`.

Comment: Make sure you compile with no optimization. Optimizing your code gives too many liberties to the compiler (for example: it may compile `int main(void) { puts("1 \n2 \n3 \n4 \n5 "); }` rather than your code ... and 'pretend' puts is at the same line as the original printf)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keep tracing even if it looks like its not going inside the loop. Sometimes the way the code is generated, the execution in the debugger is not linear. In fact as you keep tracing, keep a watch for output of the printf from the program.